# Bash: var null in a condition

Tags: bash, var

Here is the example:

```
$ credits="29" ; echo "C=$credits" ; initial="1064" ; echo "C=$credits" ; limit=`expr $initial / 10` ; echo "C=$credits" ; if [ "$credits" -le "$limit" ] && [ ! "$initial" -eq "50" ] ; echo "C=$credits" ; then echo "C=$credtis" ; fi ; echo "C=$credits" ; echo "I=$initial"
C=29
C=29
C=29
C=29
C=
C=29
I=1064

$ c="29" ; echo "C=$c" ; initial="1064" ; echo "C=$c" ; limit=`expr $initial / 10` ; echo "C=$c" ; if [ "$c" -le "$limit" ] && [ ! "$initial" -eq "50" ] ; echo "C=$c" ; then echo "C=$c" ; fi ; echo "C=$c" ; echo "I=$initial"
C=29
C=29
C=29
C=29
C=29
C=29
I=1064
```

When var name is "c", everything is ok, but when it's "credits", I can't use var content in the if condition.
Don't understand why...

Comment: This is what's causing your problem: `"C=$credtis"`. A good example of why 'formatting your code' is important.

Comment: you made a syntax error. you wrote credtis

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an incorrectly formatted if expression in both lines of code. Specifically, the first line includes an incorrect `echo "C=$credits" ;` between the end of the `if` and the `then`:

```
if [ "$credits" -le "$limit" ] && [ ! "$initial" -eq "50" ] ; echo "C=$credits" ; then
```

should be:

```
if [ "$credits" -le "$limit" ] && [ ! "$initial" -eq "50" ] ; then
    echo "C=$credtis"
fi
```

The same error is repeated here:

```
if [ "$credits" -le "$limit" ] && [ ! "$initial" -eq "50" ] ; echo "C=$credits" ; then
```

should be

```
if [ "$credits" -le "$limit" ] && [ ! "$initial" -eq "50" ] ; then
    echo "C=$credtis"
fi
```